# need a cover stock like fake leather for booklet

Tags: print-design, texture, paper

I have a restaurant drink booklet which I'm trying to get a cover stock that has a 'leathery' feel and texture. It's meant to be taken away by customers if they like it, but the budget calls for a simple booklet so no hard cover or real leather. Right now I have just a plain black cover stock. I'm thinking I can do a faux aging, or ideally have a texture paper.

[image]

Does anyone have print experience w/ a paper that has a texture that resembles a worn feel like leather that can be professionally printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for a leatherette stock.  This is usually used for report covers and such, but can have many other uses.
http://www.bindingdepot.com/Shop-BD/PAPER-Binding-Covers/

You can print on it, however it generally works better to foil stamp.  Especially given your example photo, if you you are looking for a black cover with white print foil stamp would be the easiest option.

Fibermark has a leatherette stock that has a little more "realistic" grain to it, but can be a bit more expensive.
http://www.fibermark.com/products/jersey-cover

That should give a few ideas to take to your printer to discuss with them.  I can come up with other options if you would like.  Neenah has been picking up a lot of paper manufacturers and some of them have some really interesting stock textures, colors and finishes.